# error with reversing linked lists in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, python-dataclasses

I've been trying to write a code that will reverse the linked list and I think I've got the concept of reversing the linked list down but I cannot put it into code.

the ideal outcome should be

```
4
3
2
1
```

but I keep getting "None" on its own

full code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def printLL(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
           print(current.val)
           current = current.next
    
    
    def append(self, val):
       # creation a new node w value
       newNode = ListNode(val)
       if self.head:
           current = self.head
           # go to the end of the linked list
           while current.next:
               current = current.next
           current.next = newNode

       else:
           self.head = newNode
   
    
    def reverseList(self, head):
        prev , curr = None, head
        while curr:
            tmpval = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = tmpval
        return prev
        
testlist = LinkedList()
testlist.head = ListNode(None)
testlist.append(1)
testlist.append(2)
testlist.append(3)
testlist.append(4)
testlist.append(5)
testlist.reverseList(testlist.head.next)

testlist.printLL()
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong. No Error is presented but I cannot get the result.

Comment: You need to document your source code. In particular, what is the return value of `LinkedList.reverseList()`, and why is it passed a `head`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update **self.head** attribute of your LinkedList

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def printLL(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
           print(current.val)
           current = current.next

    def append(self, val):
       newNode = ListNode(val)
       if self.head:
           current = self.head
           while current.next:
               current = current.next
           current.next = newNode
       else:
           self.head = newNode

    def reverseList(self):
        prev, curr = None, self.head
        while curr:
            tmpval = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = tmpval
        self.head = prev  

testlist = LinkedList()
testlist.append(1)
testlist.append(2)
testlist.append(3)
testlist.append(4)
testlist.reverseList()  

testlist.printLL()
```